# Как работают алгоритмы для защиты файлов в соц сетей

Tags: php, веб-программирование, angular, безопасность, соцсети

Здравтсвуйте.

На днях задумалься как же работают стандартные алгоритмы, структурные решение высоканагруженных приложений.

И сейчас очень интересная вещь касательных всех файлов пользователей в соц сетей.

**Теперь что я уже узнал и какие вопросы есть.**

Почти все современные и попУлярные соц сети(fb, vk, linkdin...), Для хранение файлов из обмена сообщениями между пользователей, файлы и картинки из групп добавленных, и самое главное это из приватных сообщений.

**Как выглядит ссылка на любой файл(Фейсбук):**

[https://sun9-57.userapi.com/impf/{x](https://sun9-57.userapi.com/impf/%7Bx) значение}/{x значение}/{x значение}/filename.jpg?size=220x261&quality=96&proxy=1&sign={x значение}&type=album

Если копировать адрес картинки из приватных сообщении то можно зайти при помощи этой ссилки кто угодно без регистрации и входа.

И как тогда работает защита от патустаронных пользователей?
Если я могу эти x значении из этой ссылки генерировать программно, канечно это ооочень много времени займет генерация этих ссылок, но я могу уже иметь доступ приватных файлов.

Как так? как этот работает, Сейчас у меня есть соц сеть Angular, PHP Laravel,и я хочу файлы отправленные в личних сообщениях защищать от других лиц.

Я не нащел такой сайт где бы было много структурных рещений многих сложных и требующих серезную защиту решений.

Comment: "Если я могу эти x значении из этой ссылки генерировать программно" - не можете.

Comment: Защита от потусторонних пользователей это мощно :)

Comment: Вы вот ту sign сгенерите. Собственно сгенерить то не сложно, взять некие параметры от этого файла, типа его id, возможно имя, в карйнем случае md5 от его содержимого (который вы не получите пока у вас нет файла), к этому добавьте некую секретную строку, которая известна только серверу соцсети и возьмите от всего этого какой нибудь sha-1. Считается то оно быстро, но если вам не известна секретная строка, то вам придется для каждого файла перебрать всего 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 вариантов (это если тот sign 128 битный). Так что да, это долго, за пару млн лет получится наверняка

Comment: @Mike а зачем генерить sign, если можно просто использовать случайные буквы в имени файла/папки? Перебор всё равно будет примерно такой же долгий.

Comment: @andreymal Сомневаюсь, что они случайны. Никогда случайных не делал, файл искать неудобно, приходится лишнее обращение к БД делать для их получения. Они наверняка закономерны, но то же с какой нибудь подписью, что согласен, то же самое что тот sign

Comment: @Mike в БД ходить придётся в любом случае, надо же где-то хотя бы имя файла хранить

Comment: @andreymal Ну последний раз, когда делал подобное, удалось обойтись без хранения имени файла. Но задача специфическая была, имя файла должно было зависеть от названия сущности, которое могут менять модераторы. И переименовывать файлы очень не хотелось. В итоге имя файла роли для его получения не имеет и генериться из полученных для других целей данных, главное правильный путь, который из id файла вычисляется

Comment: @Mika, спасибо за комментарий, НО) (всего 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 вариантов ) это если мы ищем именно 1 файл, но если у фейсбук миллиарды пользователей, в таком случий думаю через 2 месяца работы скрипта, можем получить 1-2 рандомных файлов, или нет? каличество пользователей влияет на пробиваемость защиты? защиты?

Comment: Теоретически если запустить супер компютер потратив миллионы долларов, и запусить миллоны процессов одновременно, генерирующих этих значений можно взломать что угодно)) и некто не узнает)) так что думаю в будущем соц сети вынуждены будут менять вся структуру.